# 'Not authorized' message when trying to access spark service on Bluemix

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

When I try accessing a spark service in bluemix, I get the error message 'Not authorized':

[image]

I've used spark a lot on Bluemix on a different account without problems.  This account is a new account that I've created because I need to test spark with a 'clean' environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem went away by itself.  I guess there was just a glitch in the backend which has now been resolved.